# Cannot completely fill the screen with RelativeLayout and cannot resize on Keyboard opening

Tags: android, xml, android-relativelayout

So here is my XML. I am trying to fill the whole screen and when I view it in Eclipse, it fills the whole screen. However, when I open it on my phone, everything is smaller and there are views overlaying. I don't know what's going on.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/front"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:text="Front"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/frontInput"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/front"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/back"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/frontInput"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:text="Back"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/backInput"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/back"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/background"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/backInput"
    android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
    android:text="Background"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/colors_spinner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/backInput"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/background" 
    />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/colors_spinner" >

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/save"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Save" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/cancel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Cancel" />

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

this is what it looks in Eclipse. [image: XML IN Eclipse]

But I get this: [image: XML viewd on my phone]

Another thing is that when I open the keyboard my view does not rezise so you can see everything but smaller so you can see what you are typing etc... I have added the `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` for the specific activity but nothing is happening... Any ideas? Thanks guys...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use adjustResize it will resize everything to fit as best it can.  The other option is adjustPan, which will scroll the window so that the focused EditText will be in the view and the caret visibile.  Other than that there's no real way to control things.

In your case you have some exact heights in there, so it won't work well with a resize, since you can't shrink an exact height.

Also, never trust how things look in Eclipse.  Its an attempt to lay things out that shares no code with how Android really does things, it should be viewed as an estimate.  Real layouts may end up looking significantly different, especially for complex layouts.

Comment: So what should I do to make it work? That is what I am interested in... I want to have the design as in the first pic while having the option to rezise it when the keyboard opens...

Comment: Try aligning the spinner above the linear layout with the buttons, and aligning that linear layout with the bottom of the screen.  That should fix the non-keyboard view, I think.   With the keyboard, see how bad it looks with those changes.  The real problem is that it can't resize a fixed size EditText.  Try making sure that element has a layoutBelow and a layoutAbove and set its height to fill_parent-  that *should* make it take the remaining space after laying out the rest of the elements.

Comment: I will try this and come back to you.